# Datagridview BindingSource.RemoveCurrent removing multiple rows

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have an Access DB but I'm having problems with `RemoveCurrent` method deleting multiple rows instead of one row only.
In  the form I have a combobox that allows the user to choose 
which item he wants to see/delete.
When the user press the delete button the code goes to a form where I have  all my tables and compares the name that's on the combobox with every row in the games' table that has 2 columns, one with the name and the other one with the date, both are primary keys, that way the user can add multiple games with the same name or date as long as the game isn't exactly equal to one already in the table.

But when it deletes the row that matches with the selected row in the combobox it deletes not only that corresponding game but also deletes every single game that has the same date.
I want it to delete the matching game only.
My delete function is down below.

```
Private Sub but_eliminar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles but_eliminar.Click
    Tabelas.Show()
    'Tabelas is the form with every table in the database
    Tabelas.JogoBindingSource.MoveFirst()
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Tabelas.jogos.Rows
        cri = Tabelas.jogos.CurrentCell.RowIndex
        'Compare the value on the combobox with the table that keeps the games record
        If Tabelas.jogos(0, cri).Value = ComboBox1.SelectedValue Then
            Dim op = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this game?" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Name: " & Tabelas.jogos(0, >cri).Value & vbNewLine & "Date: " & Tabelas.jogos(1, cri).Value, "Delete game", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
            If op = vbYes Then
                Tabelas.JogoBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
                Tabelas.JogoBindingSource.EndEdit()
                Tabelas.JogoTableAdapter.Update(Tabelas.Database1DataSet.Jogo)
                'Use this code to update the combobox's menu
                Database1DataSet1.Clear()
                JogoTableAdapter.Fill(Database1DataSet1.Jogo)
                ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
                MsgBox("Game deleted successfully")
                Exit Sub
            End If
            If op = vbNo Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
        Tabelas.JogoBindingSource.MoveNext()
    Next
    Tabelas.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you saying that your `MessageBox` to confirm removal only hits once and the single `RemoveCurrent` method is actually removing multiple rows?

Comment: i use the msgbox so the user can confirm that he want to remove that row but what real happen is that removecurrent is removing every single entry with the date of the selected row

Comment: Well that is bizarre. I'm sorry I don't have time to help today, but did suggest an edit to make your issue clearer to others. Good luck!